# What is the difference between Windows Defender and Microsoft Windows Malicious Software Removal Tool?

Tags: anti-virus, windows

Why does Windows Vista have two programs to remove viruses:

**Windows Defender** and **Microsoft Windows Malicious Software Removal** Tool (MRT)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[**Windows Defender**](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/products/winfamily/defender/default.mspx) runs in the background as real-time protection, looking for suspicious activities on your computer in order to **prevent** a break-out.

> Windows Defender is software that
>   helps protect your computer against
>   pop-ups, slow performance, and
>   security threats caused by spyware and
>   other unwanted software by detecting
>   and removing known spyware from your
>   computer. Windows Defender features
>   Real-Time Protection, a monitoring
>   system that recommends actions against
>   spyware when it's detected, minimizes
>   interruptions, and helps you stay
>   productive.

Main features:

- Spyware detection and removal
- Improved Internet browsing safety
- Protection against the latest threats (MS researchers and a voluntary, worldwide network gather information ybout security threads

---

You can use the [**Malicious Software Removal Tool**](http://www.microsoft.com/security/malwareremove/default.mspx) (mrt.exe) to scan for malicous software which has **already infected** your computer.

> The Microsoft Windows Malicious
>   Software Removal Tool checks computers
>   running Windows Vista, Windows XP,
>   Windows 2000, and Windows Server 2003
>   for infections by specific, prevalent
>   malicious software—including Blaster,
>   Sasser, and Mydoom—and helps remove
>   any infection found. When the
>   detection and removal process is
>   complete, the tool displays a report
>   describing the outcome, including
>   which, if any, malicious software was
>   detected and removed.

Answer (score 4):

Windows Defender is an "active" running program.  It is designed to detect and block entry of malicious programs *before* you have a security issue.

Malicious Software Removal Tool is designed to run *after the fact*.  If your system is breached, you'll run this instead.

Answer (score 0):

If Defender is only active prevention, then why does it scan? https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/is-there-a-difference-between-windows-defender/ad27e697-8f96-4f0a-9731-58b132c2b9ab

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/556052)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).